# Cannot run rspec getting gherkin (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, gherkin, turnip

I'm trying to run rspec but getting load error which raising like bellow. Done `gem install gherkin`, `gem install cucumber` and added `-r turnip/rspec` to .rspec but not worked for me.

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/turnip-1.3.1/lib/turnip/builder.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- gherkin (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

`gem install cucumber` installs `gherkin` too.

Can you uninstall these and again perform installation of

```
gem bundle install
gem install cucumber
```

and can you confirm from which directory are you running it? from root directory?

Comment: Tried as you told but no progress

Comment: Yes, solved its version mismatch issue, see bellow answer

Comment: Great! I faced the version mismatch issue. I dont see any answer? So which gem versions were having the mismatch?

Comment: Its automatically sloving dependency gherkin 4.0.0, just locked gherkin version to 2.5 at Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Created an [issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip/issues/189) at turnip where turnip 1.3.1 supports only gherkin 2.x

Comment: Got same issue with `ruby 2.3.4` with `rails 4.1.11`, just changed rspec-rails to `3.0.0` and turnip to `3.0.0`